# In redmine, is there a way to send news as an email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, project-management, redmine, issue-tracking, feed

In redmine, I would like to be able to have a news feed that all members of the project (or perhaps only developers) will see. I would prefer that it be via email, rather than as an atom feed, since everyone will check email.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807247/is-redmine-news-notifier-plugin-supports-redmine-2-2-4

Answer (score 1):

There is a patch here to do this: http://www.redmine.org/issues/2549

With this patch news are sent by email to all project members. It's a very simple patch.

Comment: It seems the default behavior now, no more patch needed.